# How to get the required output in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, excel-formula, vba

Please tell me how to do the below.

Say I have a single column A.
If the data in the 1st 3 rows 1st field is

```
XPWCS432, XPWCS440, XPWCS394, XPWCS395, XPWCS396, XPWCS397, XPWCS398, XPWCS399, XPWCS476, XPWCS390, XPWCS391
XPWCS432, XPWCS470
XPWCS432, XPWCS434, XPWCS312, XPWCS313, XPWCS314, XPWCS315, XPWCS316, XPWCS317, XPWCS318, XPWCS319, XPWCS320, XPWCS321, XPWCS322, XPWCS323, XPWCS324, XPWCS325, XPWCS326, XPWCS327, XPWCS328, XPWCS329, XPWCS330, XPWCS331, XPWCS372, XPWCS332
```

The output data should be like below

1)with out leading and traiiling comma
2)No spaces between values,no duplicates and values should be comma seperated

The below conditions should be achieved.

1) Remove the ,(comma) if it appears at the starting of string.
2) Remove any blank spaces in the string.
3) sort the string words in ascending and remove the duplicate words in the string.

The data(words)  in the field are changing from row to row i.e column1 row1 field1 may contain 3 words

row2 field1 may contain 10 words 
row3 field1 may contain  20 words

like this there may be say some 100 rows.
Thanks,
Srihai

Comment: I can see no duplicate in your example - except if PDW equals PPW (3rd, 4th token)

Answer (score 2):

I Should propose record the following macro of excel commands:

- **Text to columns**, with "space" and "comma" as delimiter to remove them.
- **Traspose** the data row to a data column.
- **Remove Duplicates** and **sort** of data.
- **Traspose** the data column to a data row.

Comment: Hi Alen thanks for answering, I tried this to the data set i have it did not work out beacause the remaining fields have varying length of words.

Comment: fully agree with "text to columns", just did it here. In addition to Alen (+1) I would tick option "treat consecutive delimiters as one" and set text qualifier to {none} to be on the safe side

Comment: @user840963 : Cloud you elaborate?, there is more data that is diferent to the example?

Comment: Hi Alen, Please find the revised question. I did this scenario using ETL tool I got the solution but eager to know how we can do using excel also.